# How to write a tesclass for a picklist

Tags: apex, unit-test, picklist, code-coverage, sobject

I have this following picklist class for which I am trying to make a testclass but I get the error variable does not exist PickListTest__c

Class

```
public class picklistController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String getPicklistData(String objectName,String fieldName){         

        List<Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().Values();
        Map<String,String> objectMap = new Map<String,String>();
        for(Schema.SObjectType f : gd)
        {
             objectMap.put(f.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix(), f.getDescribe().getName());
        }

        String query = 'SELECT '+fieldName+' FROM '+objectName;       
        List<SOBject> lstObj = Database.query(query);        
        String selVal =  String.valueOf(lstObj[0].get(fieldName)) ;  
        Schema.SObjectField sobjField = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectName).getDescribe().Fields.getMap().get(fieldName) ;
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = sobjField.getDescribe() ;
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();        
        List<picklistData> lstRet = new List<picklistData>();        
        for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple)
        {
            picklistData obj = new picklistData();
            obj.val = f.getLabel();
            lstRet.add(obj);
        } 
        return JSON.serialize(lstRet);
    }    
    public class picklistData{
        public String val{get;set;}

    }
}
```

Test

```
@isTest 
private class picklistControllerTest { 
    static testMethod void test1() { 

        Account acc = new Account(); 
        acc.Name = 'testM1'; 
        acc[0].PickListTest__c = 'Option1'; 
        insert acc; 
        getPicklistData(acc,acc.PickListTest__c);
        System.assertEquals(1, lstRet.size()); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Which line gives you the error? I'm betting that you are having a problem because of the [0] in your test class, which is unnecessary. acc is a record/variable, not an array.

Comment: @DavidSchach its indeed acc[0].PickListTest__c = 'Option1';  if I use acc.PickListTest__c = 'Option1';  I still get varable does not exist so how do I make the picklist?

Comment: `Account a = new Account(Name = 'asdf', Type='Analyst');
insert a;` worked fine for me. So does: `Account a = new Account();
a.Name = 'asdf2';
a.Type = 'Analyst';
insert a;`

Comment: @Aequitas Tried thath but get. Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void getPicklistData(Account, String) from the type picklistControllerTest

Comment: @Thomas that's because your method takes two strings in, so change it to: `getPicklistData(String.valueOf(acc.Name),acc.PickListTest__c);` or maybe you meant to pass it just `'Account'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

> `acc[0].PickListTest__c = 'Option1';`

There's no need to have `[0]` as `acc` is not a list.

You can create an SObject directly by putting the field values in the parentheses, like so:

```
Account acc = new Account(Name = 'testM1', PickListTest__c='Option1'); 
insert a;
```

And finally, with your call to the controller:

> `getPicklistData(acc,acc.PickListTest__c);`

You are passing `acc` but the method accepts (String, String). So your call should probably be `getPicklistData('Account' ,acc.PickListTest__c);` instead. You also need to reference the class since it's not in the same class: `picklistController.getPicklistData...`

Comment: tried it like getPicklistData(String.valueOf(acc), String.valueOf(acc.Type) ); but still get Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void getPicklistData(String, String) from the type picklistControllerTest

Comment: @Thomas sorry I noticed it earlier too but forgot to add it to the answer, you need to reference the method in respect to the class its in since its not in the same class. So just add `picklistController.` in front of the method call so it knows that method is in that class

Comment: Aequitas Thx I also overlooked that one. How do I assert on the return value: System.assertEquals(1, lstRet.size()); ??? Variable does not exist: lstRet

Comment: You should look at some tutorials on scoping. the variable doesn't exist because you're defining it in another class. To get access to it you'll need to use the return value so you can assign it to another object: `String lstRet = picklistController.getPicklistData('Account' ,acc.PickListTest__c);`. Something like this. But note you then can't call .size() on it since it's just a string, I'd recommend writing out the whole object (as a string) that you expect to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not created the field named PickListTest__c, then everything will fail. For your test class, use an existing field such as Type.